# how to get bar code image from given bar code

Tags: android, barcode

i want get bar code image from the given bar code number in my android app, can anyone please suggest me to that in my app? Please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use this library in android.. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/.  I have used this library in my android application and it is very easy to use.